# how to open winform faster?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a c# application and there are a lot of forms with controls.
And every time when i run my application, forms which have many controls open slow.
So is there any way to make it open faster?

Comment: How many is "many controls"?
How slow is "open slow"?

Comment: What about loading the forms invisibly, and then just `Show()` ing them when appropriate?

Comment: What are you doing in the form load method?  How many statement do you perform on your controls?

Comment: there are two grids, 8 textboxes, 5 combos, 6 buttons, 2 listboxes, 1 toolbox with 5 tools ...

Comment: Are you using the standard controls or something from a component vendor?

Comment: of course i use standart controls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the comments, there isn't one universal "make things faster" technique. You need to find the bottleneck and fix it. Here are some pointers:

- Are all your controls on all your forms added statically in the designer, or added dynamically at runtime based on environment/user details/loaded dynamically via reflection? These can significantly slow down UI load time.
- Do you have hundreds of controls on a single form? If so, consider splitting your forms to smaller chunks.
- Do you have complex logic or data access during your Form_Load events? This can also slow down UI responsiveness. Consider starting the application "clean", and then loading the data asynchronously.
- Use a profiler! Find a good, simple profiler to see where, exactly, you're spending your time. You'll often be surprised at what actually takes time. Use a trial version of a good, established profiler like [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [Ants](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), and consider buying it for the future.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making it load faster, I would recommend you to give better user experience to your user.

First, load a Splash View (with loading progress) first. On next thread running in background, load your View with a lot of controls. When your view loaded completely, hide the Splash View and show your View.

Comment: What about the Parallel Tasks Library! ;]

Answer (score 2):

In case you do something timeconsuming code with the controls in form constructor or while loading form you can write **`this.SuspendLayout();`** before that code and **`this.ResumeLayout();`** after that code. That prevents several time-killing layout operations.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the information in question provided I wolud say:

Devide controls in possible groups (It's practically impossible that user needs **all** controls **at the same time**) and put them on separate `Tabs` of tab control.
Automatically (statially) load only controls on fisrt `Tab`, for others load them dinamically.
In this case, if the user doesn't need certain functonality will never switch to the Tab that contains it, so the controls of that functionality that user *doesn't need* will not be loaded, which will provided overall faster load time.

If there is a data that should be pushed on the controls, load it in async way where it's possible,

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, but with many more controls than yours.
Considering that you have a relatively small set of controls, I think the culprit is the data access layer slowing down everything. (The loading of that grids and combos for example)

A simple action that can tell you many things is to move your data access to the form_shown event.

Answer (score -1):

In **Visual Studios** (under the Solution Explorer), you can right click your solution/solution name and select properties at the bottom of the list. If you select "Configuration Properties," then go under configuration, you can select "**Release**" instead of "**Debug**."  This will shave time off loading significantly.
Also, it is wise to avoid using "**Thread.Sleep**" in your code. This method is often used and mostly for poor code writers. About 10% of it is viable for particular circumstances, but I would avoid it at all cost.

Comment: You should only change to Release when you are releasing your application. It's not clear from the question that this is what's happening.

Answer (score -2):

Best way is to separate your solution to many layers

```
YourAppUI contains forms
YourApp.Controls contains controls
YourApp.BLL contains business logic 
YourApp.DAL contains data access layer
```

Comment: How would that make the form loading  faster?

Comment: Loading 30 MBs exe is slower than 1 MB

Comment: The amount of information has not changed, just been splitted up between several assemblies. Loading several assemblies is slower than loading one .exe.

Comment: Which assembly would not be loaded when generating the first form? And do you really belive that the .exe load time really is the biggest performance hit? I have a hard time to believe that. It's rather the form genereration that takes time.

Comment: Take this practical example, a solution with 2 proj one contains main form, the second(dll) contains some controls that not used in main form build solution, go to debug folder delete dll and double click exe you will see that exe is loading first form successfully

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions.

Comment: for question1: if you try my example you'll see every unsed dll in firstform is not loaded, for question2: you right, no it's not.